# How does CodeCommit discriminate between identical repos in different accounts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit

I ran into a weird deployment situation involving codecommit under cloudformation.

AWS CodeCommit allows me to create the same repository name in the same region in two separate AWS accounts. Both Repositories are given the SSH same endpoint (ssh://git-codecommit.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/[reponame])

I was also able to add the same SSH key to both of my IAM accounts to grant access to these two identically named repositories.

Aside from deleting the duplicate, and recreating it with a unique name, how would one discriminate which repository you are pushing to or pulling from with git?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work not long after finally asking here. What I had to do was set up different Public Keys for each AWS account, and attach the unique keys to the separate AWS IAM users. I was then able to update my .ssh config file as follows:

```
Host codecommit-acct1
  Hostname git-codecommit.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
  User [ssh_key_id_1]
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/[ssh_private_key_1]

Host codecommit-acct2
  Hostname git-codecommit.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
  User [ssh_key_id_2]
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/[ssh_private_key_2]
```

My Git repo config files were able to use 'codecommit-acct1' as a hostname, and adjusted to use the unique SSH keys, which gave AWS enough information to identify which IAM account to authenticate with.

```
[remote "origin1"]
    url = ssh://codecommit-acct1/v1/repos/[repo_name]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

[remote "origin2"]
    url = ssh://codecommit-acct2/v1/repos/[repo_name]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

I found the solution in the AWS forums here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=228206